# How to subdivide a pandas dataframe using the same index

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data as a csv file:

[image: Initial data]

and I would like to subdivide it after each 10 timeslots into 3 dataframes that should look like this:

[image]

Important there is that the index timeslot should be used for each of the 3 dataframes.

So far I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/User_1/Desktop/Data.csv", sep =";", index_col=False )
```

One problem is that when I read the data, it automatically creates a index that I do not want, altough using the argument `index_col=False`.

Do you have any idea how I can subdivide the inital dataset into the 3 dataframes with the same index? I'd appreciate every comment.

Comment: Are the rows always sorted in the order you show? (i.e., are the 10 rows always packed together)?

Comment: @GPhilo: Thanks for your comment. Yes, basically the file is always sorted in the same manner. After 10 timeslots, the new 10 timeslots are being displayed.

Answer (score 2):

If the rows are consecutive (as in your example), you can use the `chunksize` parameter:

```
dfs = list(pd.read_csv("C:/Users/User_1/Desktop/Data.csv", sep =";", chunksize=10))
```

Your DataFrames should now be in `df[0]`, `df[1]`, etc.

Comment: Cool. Thanks Ami. I upvoted and accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have the DataFrame loaded (i.e., you can't use @Ami's `chunksize`-based solution - which you should, if you have the chance), you can also obtain splits of your dataframe with:

```
import numpy as np
dfs = np.split(dataframe, range(10,len(dataframe),10))
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks GPhilo. I upvoted your answer.